# Overlap td with different background

Tags: html, css, html-table

Hi I'm working to create a newsletter template. At the moment I am stuck as I am trying to overlap two `td`, and give the top one a different background overlay.

I have attached a [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/pw17l008/pen/ZgMeBY?editors=1100), but below is the code! So you have the image in the back, with a green header in the front. I need a transparent(ish) background on that header. Any backgorund I add however seems to be placed behind that image. Any ideas?

Here is an image of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

```css
    .second-row-header {
        margin-top: -62px;
    }

    .third-row {
        border-bottom: 59px solid #f9e7ed;
    }

    .third-row-text {
        width: 420px;
        font-size: 22px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        line-height: 1.36;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 65px;
        font-family: Arial Narrow, Franklin Gothic Medium, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-stretch: condensed;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #95c11f;
        margin-bottom: 33px;
        margin-top: 0;
        line-height: 65px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .more {
        background-color: #257236;
        border-top: 13px solid #257236;
        border-bottom: 13px solid #257236;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: Arial Narrow, Franklin Gothic Medium, Arial, sans-serif;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 55px;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
        max-width: 337px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .more a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .h2 {
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: Arial Narrow, Franklin Gothic Medium, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #884a5f;
        margin: 10px 0;
        display: block;
        line-height: 1.5;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: Arial Narrow, Franklin Gothic Medium, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-stretch: condensed;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #95c11f;
        margin-top: 0;
        line-height: 45px;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<table class="bodytable" align="center">
  <!-- REPEAT START -->
  <tr mc:repeatable>
    <td>
      <table class="elementtable" align="center" bgcolor="#f9e7ed" width="690px">
        <!-- FIRST ROW START -->
        <tr class="first-row" mc:hideable>
          <td>
            <table class="imagetable">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/af180f027aa47c874c895a8b5/images/a8d65979-bcb7-4f21-87a9-fec223f046c9.png" style="max-width:690px;" alt="a8d65979-bcb7-4f21-87a9-fec223f046c9.png" mc:edit="image">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- FIRST ROW END -->
        <!-- SECOND ROW START -->
        <tr class="second-row">
          <td>
            <table class="second-row-header" width="503px" height="62px" align="center">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div>
                    <p class="h1">Bienenfutter zum</p>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- REPEAT END -->
</table>
```

Mind you this is for a newsletter template so think web 1998, most of the fancy web stuff is not usefull here!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using z-index if you want to keep your HTML structure, what this does, it bringing items up or down depending on the value. You should try something along these lines:

```
.h1{
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;        
}
```

You don't have to define the z-index, but it's good for readability and it will be useful if you want to give another elements, a diferent index. 
Also, remember that z-index, will only take action if the element has the **position** set.
You can also take a look at [this](https://cssreference.io/property/z-index/) for better context and info about z-index.